# Silverlight WCF Self Hosting seemed not to locate ClientAccessPolicy.xml

Tags: wcf, hosting, self

I've created WCF self hosting service in local machine and silverlight App gets data
from this service and send it to remote server. It worked well for more than a month
but suddenly stopped complaining well known errors clientaccesspolicy.xml not resolved.
After spending quite some time to debug, I realized it failed since the remote server 
address has been changed into IP address instead of domain addresss, for example
http://2xx.1xx.223 iso http://www.myserver.com, but domain address is not avaliable anymore
so I can't reproduce it and not sure really address changing is the criminal.

It still works fine if webserver and self hosting service both are running in my dev
machine and I can see file in my browser as "http://localhost:8000/clientaccesspolicy.xml"
but 404 error if typed "http://my-machine-name:8000/clientaccesspolicy.xml".
As I read some blogs,clientaccesspolicy.xml should be located in 80 port of local machine
but dno't know how to do and not sure it makes the problem.

My service host is configured as follows;

```
          string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000";
         //Create a ServiceHost for the OPCService type and 
         //provide the base address.
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(OpcService), new Uri(baseAddress));
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IOpcService), new BasicHttpBinding(), new Uri(baseAddress + "/OpcService"));
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPolicyRetriever), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

And clientacceccpolicy.xml is used through interface

```
       private Stream StringToStream(string result)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    }

    public Stream GetSilverlightPolicy()
    {
        string result = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <access-policy>
        <cross-domain-access>
         <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
            <domain uri=""*""/>
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
        </grant-to>
    </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
    </access-policy>";
        return StringToStream(result);
    }
```

And silverlight client uses service with proxy without ServiceReferences.ClientConfig
but with service refrence to easily get web methods.

```
       public class ServiceProxy
{
    private const string ServiceEndPoint = "http://localhost:8000/OpcService";
    private static Uri _serviceMap = new Uri(ServiceEndPoint, UriKind.Absolute);

    public static T GetProxyFor<T>()
    {
        return new ChannelFactory<T>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(_serviceMap)).CreateChannel();
    }

    [Export]
    public IOpcService SyrOpcService
    {
        get { return GetProxyFor<IOpcService>(); }
    }

    public static SYR.HMI.OpcProxy.ServiceReference.OpcServiceClient GetProxy()
    {
        return new SYR.HMI.OpcProxy.ServiceReference.OpcServiceClient();
    }
}
```

I read many threads here and google but not quite like mine and still vague to me
which one is the problem, IP address change or clientaccesspolicy file location.

Kind advice would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

HK.Lee

Answer (score 1):

I made small SL test app with 2 small methods and change endpoint address of ClientConfig
into http://ipv4.fiddler:8000 instead of http://locahost:8000.

Fiddler looks clientaccesspolicy.xml from 127.0.0.1 iso localhost,
so I changed my SL client proxy address into 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.
Everything works fine.

It's funny why localhost does not work if xap is downloaded from IP address vc domain name?
I don't know the details but anyone give some advice.

HK.lee